Android issues regarding window insets returning 0
I've seen a lot of people struggling with the windowinsets in Android. The biggest problem is most of the time that there getting 0 returned as there value. I've had this issue too and found a solution to it here it is. It's somewhere hidden in the java docs...
To get the statusbarheight or inset for compose you need to do the following.
Step 1: include the following in the oncreate of you activity
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
}

Step 2: After you included the setDecorFitsSystemWindows into your activity onCreate you need to add the following to the manifest of your activity.
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Step 3: To add the statusbar padding to your composable you can use the following modifier:
modifier = modifier.windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.safeDrawing)

Or if you want to use any other insetPaddings you can use the WindowInsets class. I've read a lot a issues on stackoverflow of people getting 0.0dp returned as there padding inset. That's because you forgot the setup part in step 1 and 2.
Hope this helps and saves you a lot of frustration.
Cheers!
